# [SOLVED]After „Android Gradle Plugin Update Recommended“ I got this error: Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4

Tags: android, android-studio

** I updated to Androidx as @androidkiller in the comments wrote**

I had an example app of a Navigation Drawer from a long time ago, incase I would need it someday. The day was today. After opening it today I got a message telling me I had to update the gradle plugin.
[image]

So I updated it and unfortunately I got an error: I got this error: Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4.

[image]

Unfortunately I don't know where to go to fix the error. I did try clean and rebuild the project but it didn't helped. Also I tried some solutions from other post having the same problem but another Gradle version but it didn't help. Like going to Android SDK and the to the Android Tools and click the missing constraint layout versions.
Any thoughts?

Comment: If you are updating then update to androidx instead of support library

Comment: So @AndroidKiller, I just have to Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX and that's all?

Comment: yes but you have to modify something if needed.